# How to implement different clicklisteners for group items in Expandablelistview in Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

So my expandablelistview looks like(Sorry i can't post images i have less than 10 reputation).In group item layout file i have one textview & one imageview like this:

```
Textview         Imageview(info icon)
Textview         Imageview(info icon)
```

What i want is on clicking the info icon on right it should display toast for few seconds giving info about this group & if i click on textview it should expand normally displaying child items under it.

My 2 layout files look like this :
Mainlayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

      <ExpandableListView
          android:id="@+id/lvexp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:groupIndicator="@null"
          android:background="@drawable/back">
     </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GroupLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblheader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#24B9FF" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/help_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
     android:paddingTop="12dp"
     android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp" />
```

How can i handle click on imageview to show toast.I have implemented onGroupClick & i am able to expand groups on click.But how can i implement click listener for Imageview?

Please help.I don't have any other alternative but to use Expandablelistview in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are attaching this `groupLayout xml` to your adapter..actually you have to implement method `getGroupView()` inside your `ExpandableListAdapter`. There you can inflate this layout and access all the views from this layout and write click listeners for this layout..

Ok..this is the sample getGroupView() implementing clicklisteners for your reference:

```
@Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                v= mInflator.inflate(R.layout.group_layout, null);
            }

            TextView text = (TextView )v.findViewById(R.id.your text id);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.your image id);


          text .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ///your code here
       }
        }
    });



       image .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ///your code here
       }
        }
    });

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Dude i am doing exactly what you are trying to say.I have just showed grouplayout xml here because i want to show how my group items look like.Can you tell me how can i write click listeners for textview & imageview separately.

Comment: I have edited the answer showing code for writing clickListeners for you views....

Comment: Thanks man.But one question since all my textview & imageview are from single xml(See my Grouplayout.xml) .So each one would be having same id so how can i know which imageview(under which row was clicked).Sorry if i am disturbing you with stupid questions.Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey, we all are here to get disturbed...ok..each getGroupView() gives you parameter "int groupPosition" so you can track which row you have clicked with this parameter.